# Python mysql error

Tags: python, mysql

I have these codes where i simply take some input and try to store these datas in the mysql database. The database is connected, however some error seem to occur while executing them. The program seems to work without using the function, so i'm assuming there's some problem in the function. I'm a python newbie, any help will be appreciated.

```
from tkinter import *
import mysql.connector
import mysql.connector.cursor


class Register():
def __init__(self,master):
    frame = Frame(master)
    frame.grid()

#MySql Connection
    self.host = 'localhost'
    self.database = 'python_mysql'
    self.user = 'root'
    self.password = 'sparsha'
    self.db = mysql.connector.connect(self.host,self.database,self.user,self.password)



  #Labels
    self.lbl1 = Label(frame,text = "Name")
    self.lbl3 = Label(frame,text = "Email")
    self.lbl4 = Label(frame,text = "Tolerance")

    self.lbl1.grid(row = 0, column =0, sticky = W)
    self.lbl3.grid(row = 2, column =0, sticky = W)
    self.lbl4.grid(row = 3, column =0, sticky = W)

   #Entry
    self.txt1 = Entry(frame)
    self.txt2 = Entry(frame)
    self.txt3 = Entry(frame)

    self.txt1.grid(row = 0, column =1)
    self.txt2.grid(row = 2, column =1)
    self.txt3.grid(row = 3, column =1)

    #Button
    self.btn1=Button(frame,text = "Submit",command=self.btn1submit)
    self.btn1.grid()

def btn1submit(self):
    print("Button clicked")
    user_data = ("INSERT INTO user_data(Name, Email, Tolerance) "
           "VALUES (%s, %s, %s)")
    value = (self.txt1.get(),self.txt2.get(),self.txt3.get())
    print(value)
    # Insert new data
    self.cursor = self.db.cursor()
    self.cursor.execute(user_data, value)
    self.db.commit()
    self.cursor.close()
    self.db.close()

root = Tk()
c = Register(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Upon execution, the errors are listed as below:

```
File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "C:/Users/Sparsha/PycharmProjects/untitled/Graphical Password     Authentication/Register.py", line 50, in btn1submit
self.cursor = self.db.cursor()
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 1383, in cursor
raise errors.OperationalError("MySQL Connection not available.")
mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError: MySQL Connection not available.
```

Comment: @YMartin I think that is just an indentation issue in the posting.  Both "functions" are clearly intended to be methods of the class.  @user - what happens if you get rid of the `import mysql.connector.cursor` line?

Comment: @AlanHoover removing that line actually gave the very same error I had posted earlier. No changes

Comment: I don't know if it will help, but did you try working with some other MySQL database driver like `MySQLdb` ?

Comment: Probably related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14564359/mysql-in-python-connection-closes-in-for-loop-after-first-cycle

Comment: @FunkySayu Actually, not. I had used MySQL with c# before, so I went along with it for python as well. MySQL is actually connected with python, no problem there. The problem seems to be with  #Insert new Data' section of the code. Removing it actually makes the program run without error. But the SQL doesn't work.

Comment: do you intend to close the connection after the button is pressed once??

Comment: @Digvijayad The program is supposed to store the user input once into the database after the user has clicked the button. So, closing it there seems about right.

Comment: Looks like you're setting value as a tuple and passing it in the first parameter. You should just be passing one string with commas in between

Comment: @FirebladeDan I just tried it, doesn't seem to affect the outcome.

Comment: Check out my below solution. For sure a select query works correct? If this doesn't work I'm pretty sure you aren't connected to the db. You should try this module at that point http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_database_access.htm

Comment: @user5177957 Try my code below, It works fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code with these improvements. It works flawlessly.

```
from tkinter import *
import mysql.connector

class Register(object):
    def __init__(self, master):


        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.grid()

    #MySql Connection
        self.host = 'localhost'
        self.database = 'python_mysql'
        self.user = 'root'
        self.password = 'sparsha'
        self.db = mysql.connector.connect(host=self.host,database=self.database, user=self.user, password =self.password)
        self.cursor = self.db.cursor()


      #Labels
        self.lbl1 = Label(frame,text = "Name")
        self.lbl3 = Label(frame,text = "Email")
        self.lbl4 = Label(frame,text = "Tolerance")

        self.lbl1.grid(row = 0, column =0, sticky = W)
        self.lbl3.grid(row = 2, column =0, sticky = W)
        self.lbl4.grid(row = 3, column =0, sticky = W)

       #Entry
        self.txt1 = Entry(frame)
        self.txt2 = Entry(frame)
        self.txt3 = Entry(frame)

        self.txt1.grid(row = 0, column =1)
        self.txt2.grid(row = 2, column =1)
        self.txt3.grid(row = 3, column =1)

        #Button
        self.btn1=Button(frame,text = "Submit",command=self.btn1submit)
        self.btn1.grid()



    def btn1submit(self):
        print("Button clicked")
        user_data = ("INSERT INTO user_data(Name, Email, Tolerance) "
           "VALUES (%s, %s, %s)")
        value = (self.txt1.get(),self.txt2.get(),self.txt3.get())
        print(value)
        # Insert new data

        self.cursor.execute(user_data, value)
        self.db.commit()
        self.cursor.close()
        self.db.close()
root = Tk()
c = Register(root)
root.mainloop()
```

**Edit**
you also don't need the `import mysql.connector.cursor`

Comment: Ah! creation of cursor in class creation. Good stuff!

Comment: aye aye... that and the use of keyword arguments. Was getting error without them.

Comment: What keyword arguments do you speak of? I'm just curious. host=self.host? OMG! that's right. I'm curious how he was ever able to connect tho! Weird.

Comment: yes, without them I was getting this error. `TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 5 were given` .   I think they are called keyword arguments, not sure about the exact term.

Comment: wow, thanks! This actually helped. Also, @FirebladeDan thanks for your input on this!

Comment: Yup! Np. Mark his answer btw as the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
user_data = "INSERT INTO user_data(Name, Email, Tolerance) VALUES ({0}, {1}, {2})".format(self.txt1.get(),self.txt2.get(),self.txt3.get())

print(user_data)
```

Print and paste your query please

The execute should look like this

```
self.cursor.execute(user_data)
```

Something quite odd is happening do this for troubleshooting purposes

```
cursor = self.db.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT Name from user_data")
rows = cursor.fetchone()
print(rows)
```

Comment: Program is taking the input, but is not storing it into the database.

Comment: Database is connected. I tried the same program without classes and functions and it worked like a charm. It took my input and then stored it in the database. So, no problem with the connection.

Comment: Ok that's good. can you do print(self.txt1.get()). What is it showing?

Comment: print(self.txt1.get()) displays the first entry value. I don't understand the problem here. It keeps displaying the same error with self.cursor = self.db.cursor() and if i remove this line and the three lines below it, no error is displayed.